# php isset and is_null: problems with notset values and null-values in php condition

Tags: php, null, isset

This is for preparing a string for a mysql-query. The problem is about the NULL.
I want ONLY the 'd'-column to be NULL (if set as null in data-array). the problem is that 'isset' is false if null and 'is_null' is also true if not set..

*So how can I fix that?*

I have the following in php:

```
<?
$data = array(
    array('id' => 1, 'c' => '', 'd' => NULL, 'e' => '', 'f' => '', 'i' => 'ciao', 'j' => '', 'k' => ''),
    array('id' => 2, 'b' => '', 'c' => '', 'd' => NULL, 'e' => '', 'f' => 'hello', 'g' => '', 'h' => '', 'i' => ''),
);

$col = array('id', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k');
$insert = $update = array();

foreach (array_values($data) as $key => $val){
    $val_stack = array();
    $insert[$key] = "(";

    foreach ($col as $c){
        if (isset($val[$c]) && is_null($val[$c])) $val_stack[] = 'NULL';
        else if (isset($val[$c])) $val_stack[] = "'".$val[$c]."'";
        else $val_stack[] = "''";
    }

    $insert[$key] .= implode(', ', $val_stack).")";
}

foreach (array_diff($col, array('id')) as $v){
    $update[] = $v == 'd' ? "$v=COALESCE(VALUES($v), $v)" : "$v=VALUES($v)";
}

echo "INSERT INTO table (".implode(', ', $col).") VALUES ".implode(', ', $insert)." ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ".implode(', ', $update);
?>
```

THIS OUTPUTS:

> INSERT INTO table (id, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k) VALUES ('1', '',
>   '', '', '', '', '', '', 'ciao', '', ''), ('2', '', '', '', '',
>   'hello', '', '', '', '', '') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE b=VALUES(b),
>   c=VALUES(c), d=COALESCE(VALUES(d), d), e=VALUES(e), f=VALUES(f),
>   g=VALUES(g), h=VALUES(h), i=VALUES(i), j=VALUES(j), k=VALUES(k)

If I comment the "isset" in the inner "foreach" (`if (/* isset($val[$c]) &&  */is_null($val[$c]))`) it outputs:

> INSERT INTO table (id, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k) VALUES ('1',
>   **NULL**, '', **NULL**, '', '', **NULL, NULL**, 'ciao', '', ''), ('2', '', '',
>   **NULL**, '', 'hello', '', '', '', **NULL, NULL**) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
>   b=VALUES(b), c=VALUES(c), d=COALESCE(VALUES(d), d), e=VALUES(e),
>   f=VALUES(f), g=VALUES(g), h=VALUES(h), i=VALUES(i), j=VALUES(j),
>   k=VALUES(k)

THE OUTPUT I WANT:

> INSERT INTO table (id, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k) VALUES ('1', '',
>   '', **NULL**, '', '', '', '', 'ciao', '', ''), ('2', '', '', **NULL**, '',
>   'hello', '', '', '', '', '') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE b=VALUES(b),
>   c=VALUES(c), d=COALESCE(VALUES(d), d), e=VALUES(e), f=VALUES(f),
>   g=VALUES(g), h=VALUES(h), i=VALUES(i), j=VALUES(j), k=VALUES(k)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **array_key_exists($c,$val)** instead of **isset($val[$c])**. It works very consistent. I had the same problem solved that way.